# Seleccionar todas las variables categóricas

Tags: r

Quiero pasar todas mis variables categóricas a variables dummy 0-1.

Para ello hago algo como lo siguiente:

```
library(fastDummies)

dummy_cols(datos,  select_columns = c("V.categorica1", "V.categorica2"....))
```

¿Hay alguna forma de seleccionar automáticamente todas las categóricas para hacer...

```
todas_categoricas <- ###
dummy_cols(datos,  select_columns = todas_categoricas)
```

Answer (score 3):

Me auto-respondo, por si a alguien le interesa.

Localizar todos los atributos categóricos de un df

```
fact<-sapply(datos, function(x) {
  is.factor(x)
})
```

Obtener sus nombres:

```
factores<-colnames(datos[fact])
```

y a partir de aquí, pues lo utilizo donde quiera.

```
dummy_cols(datos,  select_columns = factores)
```